# AS3 loader causes securityError #2044 despite crossdomain.xml

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, cross-domain

I'm working on a online painting application.

The application swf as well as the backend server is located here:
http://217.150.244.137/Client.swf

there is a crossdomain.xml located in the root as well:
http://217.150.244.137/crossdomain.xml

I load the canvas images from the server like this:

```
var _loader:Loader = new Loader();
//make sure it's really not comming from the cache
var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url+'?nocache=' + new Date().getTime());
var requestHeader1:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("pragma", "no-cache");
var requestHeader2:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Expires", "Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT, -1");
var requestHeader3:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
urlRequest.requestHeaders.push(requestHeader1);
urlRequest.requestHeaders.push(requestHeader2);
urlRequest.requestHeaders.push(requestHeader3);
var context:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(true);

_loader.load(urlRequest, context);
_loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onLoadError);
_loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onDataLoaded);
```

Still, the swf doesn't work when embeeded from another page

i get a

```
Error #2044: SecurityErrorEvent unverarbeitet. text=Error #2170: Verletzung der Sicherheits-Sandbox: http://www.pictonauts.theaterspektakel.ch/Client.swf kann keine HTTP-Header an http://217.150.244.137/images/wall/4/img_-2_-1_4.jpg?nocache=1331058396137 senden.
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, try this crossdomain.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>    
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy> 
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/> 
    <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*" secure="false" />
    <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*" secure="false" /> 
</cross-domain-policy>
```